row_number could not be used in array_to_string(array_to_agg function
I've emp table which contains name & name2 field.
I need the output in a single line.
As i dont have unique id(emp_id) in this table, i am getting error as below :-
ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot contain window function calls
LINE 1: ...elect array_to_string(array_agg(concat(name,name2,row_number...
Query used :-
select array_to_string(array_agg(concat(name,name2,row_number() over())),'') from emp
Expected result :-
Gopal---Anantha---1Radha---Meenakshi---2
Please help me
create table emp(name varchar(10), name2 varchar(10));
insert into emp values('Gopal','Anantha');
insert into emp values('Radha','Meenakshi');

Any one can tell the solution for this

I found the solution
select array_to_string(array_agg(concat(CASE WHEN a.rn = 1 THEN 'NEW' ELSE a.name END,a.name2)),'') from (
 select row_number() over() rn,name,name2 from emp) a

Result is :-
NEWAnanthaRadhaMeenakshiKolahalanGopal
